# flex vdividedbox functionality in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

how can i have the functionality of vdividedbox/hdividedbox  flex control in silverlight. I could not find a equivalent control in silverlight.

thanks
ramneek

Answer (score 1):

I just started to look into this today.  Came across this post and it seems the GridSplitter is what you're looking for?

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/128033/286865.aspx

Here's the link to the tutorial video using the GridSplitter

http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/mtaulty/silverlight-using-a-gridsplitter